Zephyr flash project error - west flash command fail
I'm referring to the following getting started guide: https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/develop/getting_started/index.html
west build -p always -b rpi_pico samples/basic/blinky

I'm getting the below error when I run west flash.
OS: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Development Board: Raspberry Pi Pico W
Debugger/Flasher: Raspberry Pi Debug Probe
I've connected the Debug Probe  to the Debug Connector on Raspberry Pi Pico W.
I've installed J-Link driver. I've installed openocd.
Output
(.venv) admin@admin-desktop:~/zephyrproject/zephyr$ west flash
-- west flash: rebuilding
[1/10] Performing build step for 'second_stage_bootloader'
ninja: no work to do.
[3/3] Completed 'second_stage_bootloader'
-- west flash: using runner openocd
-- runners.openocd: Flashing file: /home/admin/zephyrproject/zephyr/build/zephyr/zephyr.hex
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.11.0+dev-00728-gb6f95a16c (2024-05-29-12:13)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
set_adapter_speed_if_not_set
swd
Can't find target/rp2040.cfg
FATAL ERROR: command exited with status 1: /home/admin/zephyr-sdk-0.16.8/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/openocd -s /home/admin/zephyrproject/zephyr/boards/raspberrypi/rpi_pico/support -s /home/admin/zephyr-sdk-0.16.8/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/share/openocd/scripts -f /home/admin/zephyrproject/zephyr/boards/raspberrypi/rpi_pico/support/openocd.cfg -c 'source [find interface/cmsis-dap.cfg]' -c 'transport select swd' -c 'source [find target/rp2040.cfg]' -c 'set_adapter_speed_if_not_set 2000' '-c init' '-c targets' -c 'reset init' -c 'flash write_image erase /home/admin/zephyrproject/zephyr/build/zephyr/zephyr.hex' -c 'reset run' -c shutdown


You are using openOCD 0.11, but according to the docs, you need at least 0.12 to use the SWT interface with debugger.
Check out https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/boards/raspberrypi/rpi_pico/doc/index.html#using-openocd
